# Why can't Google Assistant read some pages aloud?

Tags: html, google-assistant

I hope it's the right channel to ask this question.
I've searched a lot unsuccessfully.

I've noticed that Google Assistant is sometimes unable to read some web pages.
Here is a basic one that fails:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="Description" CONTENT="Sample for Google assistant">
    <title>Sample for Google assistant</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <h1>A title</h1>
<p>
    Here is an text sample.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you know which criteria should be met for Google Assistant to be able to read a page?
Is it related to the structure of the page, the domain name or something else?

Many thanks in advance!

Best,
Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad someone finally asked.

The page must have at least 2 paragraphs and the first paragraph must be at least 270 chars long it seems. I just did rigorous testing and discovered this.

the below will work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="Description" CONTENT="Sample for Google assistant">
    <title>Sample for Google assistant</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>A title</h1>
    <p>
    Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.
    </p>
    <p>
        Here is an text sample.
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

In addition even though you didn't ask this: Google assist also seems to not be able to read content that is more than 4 divs deep.
For example I had to comment out the below divs to get my own webpage to work, not exactly sure why but i assume its the div depth.

```html
<html lang="en">
   <body class="bg-light">
      <div class=" ">
         <div class="content">
            <div class="container container-small bg-white Pa_50px rounded my-2">
               <div style="" class="row">
                  <!-- <div style="" class="Wi_100Per   BoSi_BoBo"> -->
                     <!-- <div style="vertical-align:top;" class="Wi_100Per    d-inline-block"> -->
                        <!-- <div class="p-2"> -->
                          <!-- <pre style="white-space: pre-wrap;"> -->
                            <p>
                              Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.Here is an text sample.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                              Here is an text sample.
                            </p>
                          <!-- </pre> -->
                        <!-- </div> -->
                     <!-- </div> -->
                  <!-- </div> -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Footnote: of course make sure you're using Chrome to start with. Also I acknowledge that you experienced that you only need one paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer. Unfortunately I still get the same error, even with your first example "Sorry looks like there was a problem, but you can try again later".
I have an up-to-date  Samsung S8

Comment: Update: it does not work on Samsung Internet. But both, your page and mine, now work when I use Chrome.

Comment: Cool I was gonna say that Google assist cache need clearing but I don't even know how that's done so. My pleasure.

Comment: I've noticed that 1 paragraph only works too. The main issue (at least for me) was not to use Chrome.
Can you update your post and I'll be very glad to mark it as correct ;-)

Comment: No sorry that is my answer otherwise write your own answer I think my points were important as they were my exact experience.

Comment: I'll add a footnote but nothing more

Comment: I am displaying text exactly as you did in your answer and it works. However, usually the read aloud feature has the feature of being able to tip on text so the reader jumps to that position. What do I need to adjust to have this feature? Also the page is frozen for me, so I cannot scroll the text either with the provided example HTML. Additionally, the reader reads the time (displayed on the android status bar) and the domain of the website ... is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: For me it seems to "make a screenshot" of the current screen when I tell it to read aloud on that webpage and then it just reads the entire screen, including the google assistant menu button "read aloud" etc. So it does not seem to read the actual website.

Comment: Sorry not sure havent worked on this in a while